# How can I add an OR generic type constraint on a function that accepts Any

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, foundation

I have an initializer that accepts a variadic parameter, but I want the arguments to be only one of two types:

- A custom class, say `MyCustomNSOperation`
- A tuple of `(MyCustomNSOperation, () -> Bool)`

How can I achieve that in Swift 2.0? I currently have my initializer written like this but I think it's too permissive:

```
init(items: Any ...) {

}
```

And somewhere in the class, I iterate through all of the items, check their types, and if it's not one of the two types I want to restrict to, I throw a `fatalError`.

```
for i in 0..<self.items.count {
    guard self.items[i] is MyCustomNSOperation || self.items[i] is (MyCustomNSOperation, () -> Bool) else {
        fatalError("Found unrecognised type \(self.items[i]) in the operation chain")
    }
}
```

If it is, I execute one of the two overloaded versions of another function.

I've also looked at protocol compositions too but the type constraint logic enforced there is an AND, not an OR (i.e., the item has to conform to *both* types, not just one of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just abstract these objects into a protocol and use that in your class, and use a struct instead of a tuple:

```
protocol MyItem {
    func doSomething()
}

class MyCustomNSOperation: NSOperation, MyItem {
    func doSomething() {
        print( "MyCustomNSOperation is doing something..." )
    }
}

struct OperationWithClosure: MyItem {
    let operation: MyCustomNSOperation
    let closure: () -> Bool

    func doSomething() {
        print( "OperationWithClosure is doing something..." )
    }
}


class MyClass {

    let items: [MyItem]

    init(items: MyItem...) {
        self.items = items
    }

    func doSomethingWithItems() {
        for item in items {
            item.doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this neat solution. (& And I really like the original question too.) I have a question: What is the advantage of making `OperationWithClosure` a `struct` rather than declaring it as a `class` and giving it an `init`.

Comment: The struct automatically synthesizes an initializer that allows you to provide a value for each property, and you get built-in immutability and value semantics when working with it.  There are disadvantages as well—for example, the onus is entirely on you to make it `Equitable` and implement the `==` operator if you want check equality or use collection methods and filters and rely on `==` internally.